# How to define pivot columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

When you use Gaussian elimination to solve a homogeneous system of linear equations, you end up with "pivot variables" and "non-pivot variables".  The non-pivot variables have the property that they can each be chosen freely, and once specified, they uniquely determine a solution to the equation.

I'm looking for a characterization of these free variables that depends on the operator $A$ and the choice of basis $\{b_i\}$ but does not refer to the Gaussian elimination process itself.

For example, you could look at the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$ and determine that any two of the variables can be chosen freely and uniquely determine the third, whereas one variable is insufficient and three variables is too many to be chosen freely.

For another example, take $$x_0 + x_1 + x_2 = 0\\ x_0 + x_3 + x_4 = 0.$$

The set $\{x_0, x_2,x_3\}$ consists of variables that can be freely chosen and uniquely determine a solution. In contrast, $\{x_0,x_1,x_2\}$ cannot be chosen freely, despite having three variables.

My goal is to find a test that can identify which sets of variables uniquely and freely determine a solution. My starting point is Gaussian elimination, where the non-pivot rows show you one such subset of variables. I would like to be able to characterize all such sets of variables, without reference to Gaussian elimination.

---

Here's my attempt.

- Let $A$ be a matrix with basis $B=\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}$.
- Reduce $A$ using Gaussian elimination. Let $N$ be the submatrix of $\text{rref}(A)$ consisting of the non-pivot columns. I believe $N$ is equivalent to the kernel map for $A$ expressed in our basis, in which case it can be defined without referring to the elimination process—is that right?
- Consider a subset of variables $E\equiv \{e_1,\ldots, e_d\}\subseteq \{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}$. These variables might have the desired property, or not.
- To determine whether $E$ has the desired property (i.e. the variables of $E$ may be chosen freely, and when they are chosen, they uniquely determine a solution to the homogeneous equation.), consider the linear map $Q:\mathbb{R}^d \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ induced by the inclusion of $E$ into $B$.  The requirement is that $QN$ is the identity map $I_{d\times d}$. (Or maybe just that $QN$ is invertible.)
- I got this definition by trying to formalize the idea that each basis vector in $E$ meets (has a nonzero dot product with) the columns of the null matrix in exactly one unique place. That is, it forms a kind of identity sub matrix. Because it meets each vector exactly once, we know that the variables can be chosen freely and uniquely determine a solution.

Is this right? Is there a better formulation? Thanks for your help.

---

P.S. For example of how to apply this method, consider the following separate problems $A_1 = [1,1]$, versus $A_2 = [1,0]$.  Each of these problems is a system with two variables and one equation $(A : \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with $m=2$, $n=1$). Each has a one-dimensional space of solutions (the nullity of $A$ is $d=1$).

Our basis of variables $B$ consists of the standard basis vectors. Any set of $d=1$ vectors (i.e. the singleton sets $\{e_1\}$, $\{e_2\}$) is a candidate for being a complete set of free variables. To test them, 
we consider the inclusions of $e_1$ or $e_2$ from $\mathbb{R}^m \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$:

$$E_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ 
$$E_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

We will need the kernel maps of $A_1$ and $A_2$. These are maps $\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.

The kernel of the matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ are, respectively:

$$K_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ -1\end{bmatrix}\qquad u\mapsto \langle u,-u\rangle$$

$$K_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\qquad v \mapsto \langle 0, v\rangle$$

When we test whether $E_1$ and $E_2$ are free variables for the first matrix, we find:

$$E_1K_1 = [1]\\ E_2K_1 = [-1]$$

Whereas for the second matrix, we find:

$$E_1K_2 = [0]\\ E_2K_2 = [1]$$

By examining which of these is an invertible transformation $\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, we have determined that $\{e_1\}$ and $\{e_2\}$ are complete unique variable sets for the first system $A_1$, but only $\{e_2\}$ is a complete unique variable set for the second system $A_2$.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine all possible sets of pivot variables?

Comment: @Ian Yes, exactly. Specifically in a way that doesn't refer to the Gaussian elimination process.

Comment: I think the easiest way to think about this is to consider when a subset of $\{ x_1,\dots,x_n \}$ (in my notation $A \in \mathbb{K}^{m \times n}$) of cardinality $\mathrm{rank}(A)$ *cannot* be a set of pivot variables. Because generically all of these are admissible.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think the kernel alone can tell you all that much. As an example, why is the situation with $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ (in which either variable is a valid pivot) different from the situation with $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ (in which only $x_1$ is a valid pivot)? It's a basis-dependent thing, which is usually an indicator that there's not some nice underlying theory IME.

Comment: I see what you mean. Some defns depend on basis (e.g. no natural isomorphism between V and V*). Here, I'm looking for a definition that *does* depend on basis (because it refers to a specific set of vars), but doesn't depend on Gaussian elimination process. So still ~hoping for nice theory. Kernel map for your first example:  [[1][-1]]. Second example: [[0][1]]. Difference is that both one-variable subsets {[1,0]} and {[0,1]} have unique nonzero overlap with columns of first kernel map. Only {[0,1]} has unique nonzero overlap with second kernel map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix representing your system of equations $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$.
- Find the basis for the nullspace of $A$ in the standard way: form the augmented square matrix $[A^T | I_{m}]$ and perform Gauss-Jordan elimination, yielding some result $[M | N] $. The rows of $N$ that follow zero-rows of $M$ comprise a basis for the nullspace of $A$. Call that submatrix $N^\prime$.
- If $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix, then $N^\prime$ is a $d\times m$ matrix, where $d$ is the nullity of $A$.
- **Theorem**: Choose any $d$ columns of $N^\prime$. Those columns are linearly independent if and only if the $d$ variables are a minimal set that uniquely determines a solution to the equation $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$. (And because $m$ is the number of variables in the problem, all such sets can be found in this way.)
- Proof: First, we'll establish uniqueness then minimality.

  *Uniqueness*. The chosen columns of $N^\prime$ comprise a $d\times d$ matrix $D$. If the columns of $D$ are linearly independent, then $D$ is invertible (injective).  $D$ represents a transformation from the $d$ parameters of the null space to the specific set of $d$ variables you selected for $D$.

  To see this, note that $D$ is a composition of the $d\times m$ matrix $E$ formed by choosing $d$ rows of the identity matrix $I_m$, and the matrix $N^\prime$.  The composite $D=EN^\prime$ therefore represents a transformation taking the $d$ variables of the null space to the $m$ original variables of a full, uniquely determined solution, then forgetting (quotienting out) all but $d$ of those original variables. If this process is reversible, then the $d$ original variables can be mapped back to the $d$ parameters of the null space, which then uniquely determine a solution because $N^\prime$ is a basis.

  *Minimality*. The null space (solution space) has $d$ dimensions; therefore it takes $d$ independent parameters to determine a solution.  So if a set of $d$ variables uniquely determines a solution, that set is minimal.
- And this theorem is independent of the Gauss-Jordan elimination process: Although we used Gauss-Jordan elimination to find $N^\prime$, we didn't need to. $N^\prime$ is a representation of the kernel map of the operator $A$, which is uniquely defined independent of basis.  The basis (choice of variables) is used only to define the "column choosing" matrices $E$, which are basis-*dependent* mappings from the original set of variables.

Comment: Nice answer. A minor nitpick: it would be slightly easier to read (less mental typechecking to do) if you were explicit that $I$ is $I_m$. More importantly: I'm not entirely sure that this "doesn't reference Gaussian elimination" because it's not clear how you construct $N'$ without actually doing Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @Ian. Good idea! Thanks; updated. As for elimination, I consider it a step forward because it shows how to find all pivot rows given one set of pivot rows. But I believe the matrix $N^\prime$ is just a representation of the (basis-independent) kernel map of $A$, so Gaussian elimination isn't necessary to find it.

Comment: Sorry, $I$ was actually $I_n$ the whole time (its columns have the same length as those of $A^T$). (See how taxing that trivial task can be?)

Comment: So there is an operator $N'$ and then there is all the basis-dependent "scaffolding" that surrounds this operator that you need in order to extract indices of pivot variables from the representation of $N'$. You should spell out what all of this scaffolding is.

Comment: I see the right way to view the situation now: you identify solutions to the original problem (i.e. sets of admissible pivot indices) with submatrices $E$ of the identity with the property that $EN'$ is invertible. I think that works out...but I can't quite shake the feeling that the definition of $N'$ depends on coordinates.

Comment: The matrix $N^\prime$ depends on a choice of basis for the null space but not the original space, so it's ok: The null space of $A$ consists of all vectors that $A$ sends to 0. It's a basis-independent subdomain of $A$. Choose any basis for that subspace and combine those basis vectors into a matrix $N$. $N$ will be related to matrix $N^\prime$ by a reversible change of coordinates. For this reason, $EN$ is invertible if and only if $EN^\prime$ is.  So any basis for the null space will suffice for our matrix $N$; the relevant property of $N$ doesn't depend on basis.